# Extracción de datos python

Tags: python, visualización-de-datos

les queria hacer una consulta

tengo un archivo de texto el cual es una sola columna

[image: Datos en el texto]

Lo exporto a csv

y me quedan asi..

[image: datos csv]

Quisiera quitar el limitador  ( | ) y me  los separe por columnas.

y al final quede asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

logre hacerlo en excel

pero quisiera realizarlo en python si alguien me pudiera orientar un poco se lo agradeceria

actualmente pude leer el archivo
exportarlo a un csv pero no logro encontrar como quitar el limitador y separarlo por columnas

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
df = pd.read_fwf('datos.txt')
df.to_csv('datos.csv')
```

Aca dejo anexado el codigo

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|NºCons|Fe.doc. |Suc.|Nº doc.   |C|Cuenta    |Nombre                             |Cl|NIF             |Fe.cont.|Nº doc.oficial|Tp.co|        |Cód.mda.  |Tipo de cambio |Alg.tipos de IVA  |   Total del documento|CAI/CAE                           |
|IndImp|    Tipo|           Gravado|        No gravado|                IVA|          RNI  IVA|          Perc IVA|         Perc IIBB|             Exento|     Impto.interno| Impto.adic.munic.|       Total líneas|Motivo de exenci                  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|000001|02.09.19|0084|6100002491|D|62129     |MELONI SERGIO ANTONIO              |96|20185310249     |02.09.19|0084-00002820 |06   |        |PES       |      1,000000 |                1 |            12.808,00 |65247639847063                    |
|    SD|  21,00%|        10.585,11 |                  |          2.222,88 |                  |                  |                  |              0,01 |                  |                  |         12.808,00 |                                  |
|Región(es)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
|00 , 01 , 02 , 03 , 16 , 10 , 12 , 14                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|000002|02.09.19|0084|6100002492|D|62463     |CAMPANA CARLOS                     |96|20235209153     |02.09.19|0084-00002821 |06   |        |PES       |      1,000000 |                1 |                 0,01 |65247639847149                    |
|    SD|  21,00%|                  |                  |                   |                  |                  |                  |              0,01 |                  |                  |              0,01 |                                  |
|Región(es)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
|00 , 01 , 02 , 03 , 16 , 10 , 12 , 14                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|000003|02.09.19|0084|6100002493|D|62891     |DI PRINZIO CAMILA                  |96|27388913490     |02.09.19|0084-00002822 |06   |        |PES       |      1,000000 |                1 |            12.808,00 |65247639847283                    |
|    SD|  21,00%|        10.585,12 |                  |          2.222,88 |                  |                  |                  |                   |                  |                  |         12.808,00 |                                  |
|Región(es)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
|00 , 01 , 02 , 03 , 16 , 10 , 12 , 14
```

Comment: Tienes un problema de formato con tu archivo, no es un csv ni algun formato que conosca. Yo croe que deberías preocuparte de parsear este archivo de alguna forma para extraer la informacion que quieres.

Comment: Parece un reporte en txt, habría que quitar los recuadros y lineas, para luego usar el pipe como separador. Te sugiero que agregues una muestra significativa del archivo en tu pregunta, pero como texto no como imagen.

Comment: De acuerdo con Patricio. Por favor, sube el fichero de texto. Gracias.

Comment: Es un reporte de SAP.

Comment: @David

Deje una muestra del codigo en la pregunta,

Es un reporte del sistema SAP, me lo envian en formato txt
y deseo extraerlo borrando los separadores y las -----  para luego separar todo lo que este dentro de los pipes y ubicarlos en columnas por separado

Comment: @PatricioMoracho
Si patricio es un reporte del sistema  SAP en txt , alli lo deje anexado en la pregunta, gracias por tu respuesta, a veces tiene 10 mil lineas como en otras hasta 20 mil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo propongo atacar el problema **utilizando unicamente la libreria csv**.

Y lo haría en las siguientes fases:

1. Abrir el fichero con la libreria csv
2. Leer el fichero csv especificando el delimitador "|"
3. Recorrer cada linea (es una lista de items) del fichero csv obteniendo y fusionando solo los datos entre dos lineas ---------
4. Volver a volcar los datos obtenidos en un nuevo fichero y trabajar con este último

A modo de ejemplo:

```
import csv

itemsPerRow = list() # lista para almacenar todos los items de una fila
rows = list() # lista para almacenar todas las filas

#abrir con delimitador |
with open('ex1.csv', newline='') as f:

    #obtener todas las rows del fichero csv
    #cada row es una lista de elementos
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter='|',quotechar='|',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, )

    #recorremos las rows
    for row in reader:
        if(str(row[0]).startswith('-')): #Si el primer elemento de la lista es -, entonces es una linea de separación
            if (len(itemsPerRow)!=0): #tengo datos correspondientes a filas entre dos -------------------
                rows.append(itemsPerRow.copy())
                #vacio para volver a tomar los datos correspondientes a filas entre dos -------------------
                itemsPerRow.clear()
        else:
                for item in row:
                    itemsPerRow.append(str(item).strip()) #eliminamos espacios en blanco al principio o final del item

    # #vuelco los datos del último bloque
    rows.append(itemsPerRow.copy())

    #ahora guardo los datos en un nuevo fichero csv
    with open('ex11.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter='|')
        writer.writerows(rows)
```

Saludos,

PD: No he tratado el tema de las codificaciones. Lo dejo para ti.

Comment: vale perfecto David me pondré en eso y cualquier cosa te consulto

Comment: Si te sirve no dudes en puntuarme. Gracias.